# Membership.GetUser() - Specified method is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am using client application services to authenticate users for windows app. (SqlMembershipProvider)  Login works fine and I can grab the user name by using the following code:

```
userName =  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

I want to grab a bit more info about the user such as the email address.  I have tried the following line to get the user.

```
MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser();
```

The above line gives me a "specified method is not supported" message.  Same result if I pass in the userName as well.

Is there a way to get more detailed user info using client application services as you would in an asp.net app?  If not, I wonder if I should just create my own Web Service wrapper instead?

I'm using the 4.0 Framework.

Update:  A slice of the app.config file

```
<system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="http://PC-03/FAAppServices/Authentication_JSON_AppService.axd" credentialsProvider="BillingFormsApplication.LoginForm, BillingFormsApplication" savePasswordHashLocally="True" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="http://PC-03/FAAppServices/Role_JSON_AppService.axd" cacheTimeout="1209600" honorCookieExpiry="True" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
```

Update 2:  Stack Trace

at System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline)
   at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline)
   at BillingFormsApplication.MDIMain.MDIMain_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cs:line 340

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: What Membership provider is configured in the configuration file (app.config)?

Comment: Edited to add info on app.config file

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292283.aspx

Comment: So, Arran, if I read this correctly: "This method is not used by this class" The short answer is NO.  This won't work.  Is there another way to get more detailed user info short of just making my own web service to grab it?  If using CAS won't give ya this info it seems like it's just a "quick and dirty" auth but not very robust for a real world app.

Comment: @pStan what database server are you using and does it contain the Membership tables?

Comment: SQLExpress2008R2, and yes it does.  I can query vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers using MSSMS and see all the goodies

Answer (score 0):

SimpleMembership, as the name implies, is very simple and does not implement all of the **MembershipProvider** methods; just those required for MVC basic authentication and authorization. If you try to use a method that is not implemented you will get that exception. You can either create your own MembershipProvider from scratch or you can inherit from SimpleMembership and implement the methods that are not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

## The exception is by design

The class `ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider` does not use the method `GetUser`.

If your `app.config` is configured to use `ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider`, and you call `Membership.GetUser`, then you will always get a `NotSupportedException`.

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.clientservices.providers.clientformsauthenticationmembershipprovider.getuser